# how to style two spans that are vertically aligned and centered within a paragraph

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I am trying to create a "two-row" inline table within a paragraph. The js + class stack-block-br works, but I would like to know whether there's a better way.

Here are my attempts

```js
var x = document.querySelector('.stack-block-br');
var s = document.querySelector('.stack-block-br > span');
var v = s.innerHTML.split('<br>');
var vlengths = v.map(x => x.length);
var iv = vlengths.indexOf(Math.max(...vlengths));
var vnewelement = document.createElement('span');
var h = s.offsetHeight;
vnewelement.innerHTML = v[iv];
var b = document.querySelector('body');
b.appendChild(vnewelement);
w = vnewelement.offsetWidth;
b.removeChild(vnewelement);
x.style.width = w + "px";
x.style.height = h + "px";
```

```css
.stack {
  display         : inline-flex;
  flex-flow       : column;
  align-items     : center;
  justify-content : center;
}
.stack > * {
  width      : 100%;
  flex       : 1 100%;
  align-self : center;
}
.stack-block {
  display  : inline-block;
  position : relative;
}
.stack-block>span {
  float      : left;
  position   : absolute;
  text-align : center;
  }
.stack-block>span:first-child {
  top : -2em;
  }
.stack-block>span:last-child {
  top : -1em;
  }
.stack-block-br {
  display  : inline-block;
  position : relative;
  }
.stack-block-br>span {
  /*width    : 100%;*/
  float      : left;
  /*display  : inline-table;*/
  position   : absolute;
  text-align : center;
  bottom     : -0.2em;
  }
```

```html
<p>
  class: stack
  <b>Type</b> the following should be vertically aligned and centered. The bottom of the "stack" should align with the text in the paragraph:
  <span class="stack">
      <span>&larr;</span>
  <span>something</span>
  </span>
  this text should follow the vertically aligned and centered text.
</p>

<p>
  class: stack-block
  <b>Type</b> the following should be vertically aligned and centered. The bottom of the "stack" should align with the text in the paragraph:
  <span class="stack-block">
      <span>&larr;</span>
  <span>something</span>
  </span>
  this text should follow the vertically aligned and centered text.
</p>

<p>
  class: stack-block-br
  <b>Type</b> the following should be vertically aligned and centered. The bottom of the "stack" should align with the text in the paragraph:
  <span class="stack-block-br">
      <span>&larr;<br>something</span>
  </span>
  this text should follow the vertically aligned and centered text.
</p>
```

The stack class "works" but the top span aligns with the text in the paragraph, and I cannot center the top span over the bottom.

The stack-block aligns the bottom with the p's text but it has no width.

With some javascript stack-block-br works. Note: I cannot use offsetWidth of the spans because the 
 returns a number much larger than the actual width.

Comment: I don't understand your question two spans vertically aligned and centred in paragraph.

Comment: @prograk, If you run the code snippet and review the last paragraph you'll see an arrow over "something" within a paragraph. That's what I'm looking for. ALSO: view it in full page.

Comment: okay let me try now

Comment: I've created a sandbox as per what I understood and sharing link with you if this is what ur looking for let me know I'll add as proper answer. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-water-gngdr?file=/index.html

Comment: @prograk. your stack-block looks perfect. Thank you.

Comment: ur welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have settled upon a solution that uses a stack container: display: inline-block, a row container: display: table-row, and a cell container: display: table-cell

```css
.stack-table {
    display: inline-block;
}
.stack-table > span {
    display: table-row;
    transform: translate(0, 25%);    
}    
.stack-table > span > span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-style: oblique 10deg;
}
```

```html
  <p>
    class: stack-table
    <b>Type</b> the following should be vertically aligned and centered. The bottom of the "stack" should align with the text in the paragraph: 
    <span class="stack-table">
      <span><span>&larr;</span></span>
      <span><span>something</span></span>
    </span>
    the text that comes after the stack should follow the vertically aligned and centered text. 
  </p>
```

I decided to make the stack-table oblique to make it more noticeable. And I translated it a little (thanks @Anirudhsanthosh)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sandbox and adding code here as a proper answer.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-water-gngdr?file=/index.html

```css
span.stack-block {
  display    : inline-block;
  margin-top : 20px;
  max-height : 18px;
  }
.stack-block > span {
  display     : inline-flex;
  flex-flow   : column nowrap;
  align-items : center;
  top         : -20px;
  position    : relative;
}
```

```html
<p>
  class: stack-block
  <b>Type</b> 
  the following should be vertically aligned and centered. The bottom of the "stack" should align with the text in the paragraph:
  <span class="stack-block">
    <span>
      <span>&larr;</span>
      <span>something</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  this text should follow the vertically aligned and centered text.
</p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

i guess you need this.

i added
`line-height:1em; transform:translate(0,-25%);`
to your **stack** class.

and you can use any padding for children of **stack** class
it will automatically align.

```css
.stack,.stack-children-with-1-rem-padding {
  display         : inline-flex;
  flex-flow       : column;
  align-items     : center;
  justify-content : center;
  line-height:1em;
  transform:translate(0,-25%);
}

.stack-children-with-1-rem-padding>*{
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  class: stack
  <b>Type</b> the following should be vertically aligned and centered. The bottom of the "stack" should align with the text in the paragraph:
  <span class="stack">
      <span>&larr;</span>
  <span>something</span>
  </span>
  this text should follow the vertically aligned and centered text.
</p>

<p>
  class: stack (children with 1rem padding)<br/>
  <b>Type</b> the following should be vertically aligned and centered. The bottom of the "stack" should align with the text in the paragraph:
  <span class="stack-children-with-1-rem-padding">
      <span>&larr;</span>
  <span>something</span>
  </span>
  this text should follow the vertically aligned and centered text.
</p>
```